# how to make the grid within eso-pic in a A3 poster less visible

Tags: textpos, eso-pic

I am making a A3 poster that has a square grid as background. I would place more texts and pictures on this poster using textpos package. My question  is 1) as in the title: that is making texts and graphics more visible on top of this background and 2) is it the right way to make A3 poster?

```
\documentclass[a3,portrait]{a0poster}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor} 
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for including images
\graphicspath{{figures/}} % Location of the graphics files
\usepackage{booktabs} % Top and bottom rules for table
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption} % Required for specifying captions to tables and figures
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amsthm, amssymb} % For math fonts, symbols and environments
\usepackage{wrapfig} % Allows wrapping text around tables and figures
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage[colorgrid,texcoord]{eso-pic}
\usepackage[texcoord=false,grid,gridunit=mm,gridcolor=gray!40,subgridcolor=green!40]{eso-pic}

\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\begin{document}
\begin{textblock}{20.5}(1.5, .5)
HỘI TOÁN HỌC VIỆT NAM

KỲ THI TÌM KIẾM TÀI NĂNG TOÁN HỌC TRẺ
\end{textblock}

\includegraphics[width=22cm]{ztuong}

\begin{textblock}{20.5}(11.5, 2.5)
Some text
\end{textblock}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. I'd suggest placing the grid in the background rather than over top of the content (in the foreground). To achieve this, add the option `gridBG` as part of the options you already specify.

   In order make the grid even less visible, use colours that are closer to white. So, instead of (say)

   ```
   gridcolor=gray!40,subgridcolor=green!40
   ```

   you could use (say)

   ```
   gridcolor=gray!5,subgridcolor=green!5
   ```

   [image]

   ```
   \documentclass[a3,portrait]{a0poster}
   \usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
   \usepackage{graphicx} % Required for including images
   \usepackage[
     texcoord=false,
     grid, gridBG,
     gridunit=mm,
     gridcolor=gray!5, subgridcolor=green!5]{eso-pic}
   \usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
   \begin{document}

   \begin{textblock}{20.5}(1.5, .5)
   Here is some regular text.

   And then some more regular text.
   \end{textblock}

   \includegraphics[width=22cm]{example-image}

   \begin{textblock}{20.5}(11.5, 2.5)
   Some text
   \end{textblock}

   \end{document}
   ```
2. This depends heavily on what you want to achieve. If you poster content has a document-like feel to it, then no. If would be easier to set a regular document that you insert on an A3 page. However, if you have abstract blocks containing images, with an arbitrary layout, then this option would work.

Comment: If \pagecolor{blue} is used, then the grid by the eso-pic will not be displayed. How can I use both?

Comment: @Thumbolt: Use `\pagecolor{<colour>}` in the preamble.